# How to change the colour of bootstrap loader

Tags: colors, spinner, react-bootstrap

I included a Bootstrap spinner in a web page, but it seems that only the colors from text color utilities can be used (primary, warning...), which is quite limited. I would like to be able to change the theme of the webpage, and therefore the color of the spinner too, to a color that is not in text color utilities. Is it possible to do that and how?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/spinners/#variants):

> Alternatively spinners can be custom
> sized with the style property, or custom CSS classes.

Remove `variant` prop first as this applies `!important` styles. After removing `variant`, proceed to style with a custom class or like my example below a `style` prop - changing `color` should suffice in your case

```
<Spinner animation="border" style={{color: "green"}} />
```